# How to prompt user to try again when an incorrect input is given

Tags: java

I haven't used Java in almost two years and it's showing! :(
I am asking a user to input a binary number into the terminal which works. However, I have it currently setup to output an error and end the program if they don't put in a binary number. How can I make it so it instead keeps prompting them until they correctly enter what I am asking for? Thanks!

Comment: please take a look at similar questions and show us your effort so far.

Comment: @ Paul, I have tried the do while loops from similar questions. It only asks the user one more time then quits

Comment: Maybe something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34324730/if-a-user-types-in-a-number-that-isnt-available-the-following-message-is-printe/34324790#34324790)

Comment: @pingpeng Then it's something wrong with the conditions in the while loop. Please provide the code you've written for how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use a while loop, like this (written in pseudo code)

```
input = null
while input is not valid:
    print "Enter a valid input"
    input = readInput()

// Do something with the valid input
```